# Getting "bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Writer" error message

Tags: go

I'm trying to have some Go object implement io.Writer, but writes to a string instead of a file or file-like object. I thought `bytes.Buffer` would work since it implements `Write(p []byte)`. However when I try this:

```
import "bufio"
import "bytes"

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    foo := bufio.NewWriter(b)
}
```

I get the following error:

```
cannot use b (type bytes.Buffer) as type io.Writer in function argument:
bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Writer (Write method has pointer receiver)
```

I am confused, since it clearly implements the interface. How do I resolve this error?

Comment: I've run into this problem at least twice, and Googling for a solution was really unhelpful.

Comment: Note that the creation of a bufio is not necessary. Just use &b as a io.Writer

Answer (score 183, accepted):

Pass a pointer to the buffer, instead of the buffer itself:

```
import "bufio"
import "bytes"

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    foo := bufio.NewWriter(&b)
}
```

Comment: I ran into this and would be interested in learning why that is the case.  I'm pretty unfamiliar with pointers in Go.

Comment: Thanks Kevin, this simple mistake took an hour of my time until I googled this. :)

Comment: @hourback it has to do with the way the interface is implemented. There's actually to ways to implement an interface in Go. Either with value or pointer receivers. I think this is a really peculiar twist to Go. If the interface is implemented using value receivers either way is OK but if the interface is implemented using pointer receivers you have to pass a pointer to the value if you intend to use the interface. It makes sense since the writer has to mutate the buffer to keep track of where it's writer head.

Comment: this is the wrong answer! the newwriter has it own []byte buffer which can if the b buffer is too big , it won't capture it. if you try to use the b, it won't have the full content.

Comment: Pointer to buffer (`&b`) is already a writer! - look at answer of @aQua, his answer should be selected.

Answer (score 44):

```
package main

import "bytes"
import "io"

func main() {
    var b bytes.Buffer
    _ = io.Writer(&b)
}
```

You don't need use "bufio.NewWriter(&b)" to create an io.Writer. &b is an io.Writer itself.

Comment: This should be the right answer. If you try to create a new writer out of the buffer, you won't be able to fetch the buffer Bytes directly, which makes things much more complicated.

Comment: I wanted to understand what this is doing? Is it just to check if b implements the Writer interface?
_ = io.Writer(&b)

Comment: I think there's a small detail left out in the above answer, instead of `_` it should be a variable. That variable will be an io.Writer interface to `&b`. You then pass that variable to whatever function that accepts an io.Writer.

Answer (score 15):

Just use

`foo := bufio.NewWriter(&b)`

Because the way bytes.Buffer implements io.Writer is

```
func (b *Buffer) Write(p []byte) (n int, err error) {
    ...
}
// io.Writer definition
type Writer interface {
    Write(p []byte) (n int, err error)
}
```

It's `b *Buffer`, not `b Buffer`. (I also think it is weird for we can call a method by a variable or its pointer, but we can't assign a pointer to a non-pointer type variable.)

Besides, the compiler prompt is not clear enough:

`bytes.Buffer does not implement io.Writer (Write method has pointer receiver)`

---

Some ideas, Go use `Passed by value`, if we pass `b` to `buffio.NewWriter()`, in NewWriter(), it is a new `b` (a new buffer), not the original buffer we defined, therefore we need pass the address `&b`.

---

`bytes.Buffer` is defined as:

```
type Buffer struct {
    buf       []byte   // contents are the bytes buf[off : len(buf)]
    off       int      // read at &buf[off], write at &buf[len(buf)]
    bootstrap [64]byte // memory to hold first slice; helps small buffers avoid allocation.
    lastRead  readOp   // last read operation, so that Unread* can work correctly.
}
```

using `passed by value`, the passed new buffer struct is different from the origin buffer variable.