# How to convert (type *bytes.Buffer) to use as []byte in argument to w.Write

Tags: go

I'm trying to return some json back from the server but get this error with the following code

```
cannot use buffer (type *bytes.Buffer) as type []byte in argument to w.Write
```

With a little googling, I found [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454940/getting-bytes-buffer-does-not-implement-io-writer-error-message) but couldn't get it to work (see second code sample with error message)

1st code sample

```
buffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

for _, jsonRawMessage := range sliceOfJsonRawMessages{
    if err := json.Compact(buffer, jsonRawMessage); err != nil{
        fmt.Println("error")

    }

}   
fmt.Println("json returned", buffer)//this is json
w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentTypeJSON)

w.Write(buffer)//error: cannot use buffer (type *bytes.Buffer) as type []byte in argument to w.Write
```

2nd code sample with error

```
cannot use foo (type *bufio.Writer) as type *bytes.Buffer in argument to json.Compact
 cannot use foo (type *bufio.Writer) as type []byte in argument to w.Write


var b bytes.Buffer
foo := bufio.NewWriter(&b)

for _, d := range t.J{
    if err := json.Compact(foo, d); err != nil{
        fmt.Println("error")

    }

}


w.Header().Set("Content-Type", contentTypeJSON)

w.Write(foo)
```

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Write requires a `[]byte` (slice of bytes), and you have a `*bytes.Buffer` (pointer to a buffer).

You could get the data from the buffer with [Buffer.Bytes()](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.Bytes) and give that to `Write()`:

```
_, err = w.Write(buffer.Bytes())
```

...or use [Buffer.WriteTo()](http://golang.org/pkg/bytes/#Buffer.WriteTo) to copy the buffer contents directly to a `Writer`:

```
_, err = buffer.WriteTo(w)
```

Using a `bytes.Buffer` is not strictly necessary.  [json.Marshal()](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal) returns a `[]byte` directly:

```
var buf []byte

buf, err = json.Marshal(thing)

_, err = w.Write(buf)
```

Comment: Thank you but I require a little clarification. What would I pass to json.Compact in this situation (which I need to use to remove \n and \t)? Can you please provide a bit more information specific to my code sample? Thank you if you can help.

Comment: for example, this prints bytes to my terminal- `fmt.Println("json returned", buffer.Bytes())`, if I pass buffer.Bytes() to w.Write, won't it return a stream of bytes as well. i need json returned. Note, I can't test this because there's other problems with my browser.

Comment: @Leahcim If you want to print it, try `buffer.String()`. `buffer.Bytes()` returns the UTF-8 encoded bytes of the json text.

Answer (score 10):

This is how I solved my problem

```
readBuf, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonStoredInBuffVariable)
```

This code will read from the buffer variable and output []byte value

Comment: Did `Buffer.Bytes()` not work for you?  It seems like the easiest way.