# How to write to a file in-memory, and then send it via HTTP without using an intermediate file?

Tags: csv, file, go, memory

I need to request, process and format data to CSV, and then send them via a web service on request.

Assuming that the requested and processed data are in `data` below, I managed to do that using an intermediate temporary file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "io/ioutil"
    "net/http"
    "os"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
)

type Data struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    data := []Data{
        {"John", 30},
        {"Jane", 20},
    }
    tempFileName := "temp.csv"
    // create temporary intermediate file
    file, err := os.Create(tempFileName)
    defer file.Close()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    w := csv.NewWriter(file)
    var csvData [][]string
    for _, record := range data {
        row := []string{record.Name, strconv.Itoa(record.Age)}
        csvData = append(csvData, row)
    }
    w.WriteAll(csvData)

    // read temporary intermediate file to send it via HTTP
    fileBytes, err := ioutil.ReadFile(tempFileName)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    // send the file on request
    router := chi.NewRouter()
    router.Get("/data", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write(fileBytes)
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8087", router)
}
```

The request is successful:

```
PS C:\temp> wget http://localhost:8087/data
--2023-06-13 15:34:00--  http://localhost:8087/data
Resolving localhost (localhost)... ::1, 127.0.0.1
Connecting to localhost (localhost)|::1|:8087... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 16 [application/octet-stream]
Saving to: 'data'

data                          100%[=================================================>]      16  --.-KB/s    in 0s

2023-06-13 15:34:00 (523 KB/s) - 'data' saved [16/16]

PS C:\temp> cat data
John,30
Jane,20
```

So far so good - now I would like to get rid of the intermediate file by

- using an in-memory "container" for the CSV data to be written to
- write its contents as bytes to the HTTP writer

I still do not have a good understanding of how to use `io.*` and `bufio.*` to land on the required types:

- `csv.NewWriter()` requires an `*os.File` and returns a `*csv.Writer`
- this `*csv.Writer` contents somehow need to be extracted as `byte` ...
- ... in order to feed the `http.ResponseWriter.Write()`

What are the general mechanics (and the ones specific to this case) to approach such a problem of different types of in-memory file manipulation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`csv.NewWriter` takes an `io.Writer`, so you can pass the instance of `http.ResponseWriter` to it without writing the content to a file or memory.

Here is the demo:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
)

type Data struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    router := chi.NewRouter()
    router.Get("/data", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        data := []Data{
            {"John", 30},
            {"Jane", 20},
        }
        csvWriter := csv.NewWriter(w)
        var csvData [][]string
        for _, record := range data {
            row := []string{record.Name, strconv.Itoa(record.Age)}
            csvData = append(csvData, row)
        }
        if err := csvWriter.WriteAll(csvData); err != nil {
            // handle the error
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8087", router)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to JimB's comment (to use [`bytes.Buffer`](https://pkg.go.dev/bytes#Buffer)) as well as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23454940/getting-bytes-buffer-does-not-implement-io-writer-error-message) about using pointers to `Buffer`) I managed to get rid of the temporary file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "net/http"
    "strconv"

    "github.com/go-chi/chi/v5"
)

type Data struct {
    Name string
    Age  int
}

func main() {
    data := []Data{
        {"John", 30},
        {"Jane", 20},
    }
    var file bytes.Buffer
    w := csv.NewWriter(&file)
    var csvData [][]string
    for _, record := range data {
        row := []string{record.Name, strconv.Itoa(record.Age)}
        csvData = append(csvData, row)
    }
    w.WriteAll(csvData)

    // send the file on request
    router := chi.NewRouter()
    router.Get("/data", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
        w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
        w.Write(file.Bytes())
    })
    http.ListenAndServe(":8087", router)
}
```

The better answer is [Zeke Lu's one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76465943/903011).